# Android studio logcat displays only last line

Tags: android, logging, android-studio, logcat

I log all kinds of things using `System.out.println()` in android during test phase, but only the last print gets logged into logcat, but this only applies to one method, let me show:

onCreate:

```
    System.out.println("This line isn't visible");
    System.out.println("Neither this one, only the third one");
    System.out.println("V TEST on create " + savedInstanceState);
```

onSave:

```
    System.out.println("TEST on save");
```

onRestore:

```
    System.out.println("how is this possible");
    System.out.println("TEST on restore foo 2");
```

Output in logcat:

```
09-20 16:59:50.773    1125-1125/myapp.ironpath I/System.out: V TEST on create null
09-20 17:01:36.513    1125-1125/myapp.ironpath I/System.out: TEST on save
09-20 17:01:36.922    1125-1125/myapp.ironpath I/System.out: V TEST on create Bundle[{lots of data}]
09-20 17:01:36.942    1125-1125/myapp.ironpath I/System.out: TEST on restore foo 2
```

All these method call their super method as first thing, so where is the problem? is it wrong logcat config?

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use `Log.d()`, etc?

Comment: It doesnt show anything at all when i use Log.d()

Comment: LOL i have no idea what i did but now it works :3

Comment: Sometimes it just freaks out. Restarting adb normally works for me.